# javascript interval

Tags: javascript, intervals

How can I use interval in js?  For example I want to call a function every 5 seconds?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

setInterval(openAPage(), 5000);

function openAPage() {
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var myWin = window.open("http://www.sabah.com.tr","_blank")
var endTime = new Date().getTime();
var timeTaken = endTime-startTime;
</script>
```

This script doesn't work, anyone know why?

Comment: `openAPage()` will execute the function, `openAPage` is only a reference to the function

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These answers are thorough and good; I just want to specifically fix yours.  See the other answers for HOW/WHY.

```
setInterval(openAPage, 5000);
```

Note the lack of `()`.

Also, you're missing the closing `}` on the openAPage() function.

Answer (score 4):

```
setInterval(function(){
  /* your code here */
}, 5000);
```

And if you need to pass data to the function, you can do it with a closure:

```
setInterval(function(param){
  return function(){
    console.log(param);
  };
}("hello"), 5000);
```

will print "hello" to the console.

Answer (score 3):

```
setInterval(functionName, 5000)
```