# Auto refresh on specific pages and with constant time of 5 sec

Tags: javascript

I have 3 file as following :

1. output-xml.php
2. phpsqlajax_map.htm
3. database.php

In order to get the latest information on phpsqlajax_map.htm, I have to refresh "3" and then no "1" first. For user,thy will only open phpsqlajax_map.htm, while 1 and 3 only work behind the system.

What I want to ask is, how to write a javascript in order to make 1 and 3 refresh automatically in every 5 second and " even without opening it out ". Hope u all understand my poor english.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript interval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454430/javascript-interval)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) function which allows you to execute some custom javascript method at regular intervals. This method could send an AJAX request and refresh the corresponding DOM element.

Comment: Sir.i dont really understand. can u explain in more detail ?

Comment: @user647527, you would use the function like this: `window.setInterval(function() { ... }, 5000);` and in the place of `...` you would put your AJAX code that will call the remote page. This code will execute every 5 seconds. Once each AJAX call completes you would update the corresponding section of the DOM.